# TFS API Find Application Tier and Data Tier Servers

Tags: api, tfs, server-name

Given a TFS URL (e.g. http://tfs.mycompany.com:8080/tfs), I'd like to find all of the application and data tier servers that are registered with it (similar to how the TFS Administrative Console displays the information).

I don't know which TFS API classes I should use to retrieve this information?